# How do you find where a stored procedure is used (in other stored procedures)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I want to refactor, in a database which has thousands of SPs. Is there a quick way of finding references to that stored procedure in other SPs so I can be sure that I'm not breaking any other code when I refactor.

In the application code I can look for calls to the SP easily enough, and I can do a text search over all the various sql files which define the SPs, but it's possible there may be some SPs in the database which may be missed that way.

EDIT: The stored procedures I'm trying to locate are part of a package.

EDIT: I'm running on Oracle 11g

Answer (score 13):

`DBA_DEPENDENCIES` view has all the answers to such questions.

```
select * from DBA_DEPENDENCIES
  where referenced_owner='HR' and referenced_name='STORED_PROCEDURE_41';
```

Comment: This approach will not however work if you use dynamic sql. i.e. if you execute a procedure as part of dynamic sql. Otherwise dba_ or all_dependencies will work great.

Comment: This is helpful, and I can locate functions and procedures which are defined by a user, but I don't seem to be able to find FNs or SPs which are defined in a package. Any thoughts?

Comment: In this case one has to search for a package. `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` show us more like what will be invalidated if particular object is droped. So e.g. you can find what views references table.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to work - it's less elegant than @MindaugasRiauba's answer, but it does seem to find references from all packages.

```
SELECT * FROM all_source
where UPPER(TEXT) like UPPER('%STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME%')
```

(From [How can you tell if a PL/SQL Package, Procedure, or Function is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670164/how-can-you-tell-if-a-pl-sql-package-procedure-or-function-is-being-used)))

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, only that I needed to retrieve a list of packages that use a specific package; so I made this query, maybe it helps:

```
with dep2 as (
    select dep.*
    from all_dependencies dep
    where dep.owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'PUBLIC', 'XDB')
    and dep.referenced_owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'PUBLIC', 'XDB')
    and dep.referenced_type = 'PACKAGE'
    and dep.dependency_type != 'NON-EXISTENT'
    and (dep.referenced_owner || '.' || dep.referenced_name) != (dep.owner || '.' || dep.name)
),
dep3 as (
    select owner || '.' || name as child,
    referenced_owner || '.' || referenced_name as parent
    from dep2
)
select connect_by_root parent, lpad(' ',2*(level-1)) || to_char(child) 
from dep3
start with parent = 'SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME'
connect by nocycle prior child = parent 
and exists (select 1 from all_source where (owner || '.' || name) = dep3.child and upper(text) like upper('%optional, some string you may want to search%')) 
;
```